# How to make a image css not move at text?

Tags: html, css, image, position

I have this demo: http://vestigedayz.com/sys/adminexec/Test/

I have put a image on it (right, that folder icon) but i don't want to make it move when I randomly type on the keyboard.

```
.image{
    padding-left:1100px;
    position:fixed;

    }


    <a href=""> 
<div class="image">
<img src="images/suspect.png" width="160" height="140" alt=""> 
</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change right and top to what you want.

`position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top: 10px;`

Lose the: 
    `padding-left:1100px;
    position:fixed;`